# How to wait to finish subscribe before moving to next index in for loop in Angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular-observable

I'm using `Angular 6`.

I have an array of links and a variable to store fetched information in same order as of array one by one.

Here is what I'm trying to do using `for` loop.

```
products: any;
processedItems: Array<any> = [];

private _processItem() {

  for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
    this.scraperService.scrapSingle(this.products[i].url).subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res.status.http_code === 200) {
          const properties = this.scraperService.processSingleProduct(res.contents);

          const p_item = {};
          p_item['info'] = this.products[i];
          p_item['properties'] = properties;

          this.processedItems.push(p_item);
        }
        console.log(res);
      }
    );
  }

console.log(this.products.length);
}
```

**But how to wait for `subscribe` before moving to next index in the loop?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use promises instead of rx.js subscriptions via using toPromise method. You might need to map the **res** to json. res.map(item => item.json());

```
products: any;
processedItems: Array < any > =[];

private _processItem() {

    this.products.array.forEach(async (element) => {
        const res = await this.scraperService.scrapSingle(element.url).toPromise();
        if (res.status.http_code === 200) {
            const properties = this.scraperService.processSingleProduct(res.contents);

            const p_item = {};
            p_item['info'] = element
            p_item['properties'] = properties;

            this.processedItems.push(p_item);
        }
        console.log(res);
    });

    console.log(this.products.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just splice the p_item into your array at the required index given i.

For example instead of doing,

`this.processedItems.push(p_item);`

do this,

`this.processedItems.splice(p_item, 0, i);`

That solves your problem :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide more context or an example to make this a cmore complete answer. Thanks.